# How to enable object SharingRecordCollection in sandbox?

Tags: permission-sets, files, contentversion, sharingrecordcollection

**Context**

To retrieve all applicable files in the org and perform a data migration on ContentVersion records, we have created a permission set with `Query All Files` permission (as recommended [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381258&type=1)) and relevant pre-requisite permissions

**Issue**

When deploying the permission set from DEV sandbox to UAT sandbox, deployment failed with this error :

`Permission Query All Files depends on permission(s): Read All SharingRecordCollection, Read SharingRecordCollection`

**Findings**

This `SharingRecordCollection` object is recognised in UAT (refreshed last month) though not "queryable" nor visible in object manager, but object is not recognised in DEV sandbox which is older than UAT.
The error was fixed by providing required access level on `SharingRecordCollection` in the permission set metadata XML file

**Question** : how do we enable `SharingRecordCollection` in an org ?

[SharingRecordCollection object reference does not provide such info](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_sharingrecordcollection.htm)